# Where do I post questions about email address best practices for webmasters?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a best practices question for creating email address. Specifically, how to structure the name and domain. Which Stack Exchange site is the correct one?

For more context, right now my company structures our no reply emails like this:

> noreply@[subdomin].[domain].com (example: noreply@foobar.example.com)

I want to know if something like this is acceptable:

> noreply_[subdomain]@[domain].com (example: noreply_foobar@example.com)

My concern is  being marked as spam when, of course, it's not. The user signed up with us. We have need of this due to how our Send Grid is set up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might not be a Stack Exchange site for this.

My initial thought was that [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be a fit for this:

> Pro Webmasters is a site for asking questions about operating and
> managing your own website. Questions here are commonly about, but not
> limited to:
>
> - Search engine optimization (SEO)
> - Domains
> - Web and email hosting
> - Internet marketing
> - Website management (e.g., analytics, ads, URLs, etc…)

However, the question ["Are .xyz domains usually blocked by mail servers?"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136534/are-xyz-domains-usually-blocked-by-mail-servers) has been closed as Opinion Based. It seems pretty close to your question since it's also asking whether a certain type of email address is going to look like spam.

I checked Super User and found that ["How to actually get email DELIVERED past spam filters"](https://superuser.com/questions/1401400/how-to-actually-get-email-delivered-past-spam-filters) is also closed. According to the first comment, it's considered opinion based.

Any other Stack Exchange is likely to be even less appropriate than these two for this topic.

You might try seeing if either of those two sites have a chat room that would allow for questions that would be off-topic on the main site. Otherwise, I don't think Stack Exchange is a good fit for this question.